# How to upload file and other textbox data using plain javascript

Tags: javascript, php, file, file-upload

I want to upload an image and other input datas using plain javascript. I already searched a lot of stuff but it's different from what I wanted. So I decided to post it here. What I want is to upload an image together with other input datas.

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Description" name="desc">
      <input type="file" name="file" id="image">
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
</form>
```

**JS**

```
var myform = document.getElementById('form');

    myform.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var fileInput = document.getElementById('image');
        var file = fileInput.files[0];

        var datas = new FormData(myform);
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var url = "sample.php";
            xhr.open('POST', url, true);
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'multipart/form-data');

        xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
             if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200){
                  var response = xhr.responseText;
                      console.log(response);
              }
        };

         xhr.send(datas);
    });
```

**PHP**

```
echo $_FILES['file']['name'];
```

**OUTPUT**

*Undefined index: file*

Answer (score 0):

The content type for your request needs to be `multipart/form-data` instead of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Comment: Missing Boundary and still undefined index

Comment: I notice you haven't called the `send` method on your `xhr`. Is that line missing in the example or have you missed that? `xhr.send(datas);`

Comment: I just forget to post the send but its actually what Im doing

Comment: Have you tried printing out the $_FILES array? `print_r($_FILES)`. What is the result? Is the `desc` also not being received?